# What are these jumpers between phases and earth in a residential distribution grid?

Tags: power-electronics, mains, power-engineering

In my city, in quite a few locations there appear to be wire jumpers from each phase to the earth(?) wire. They appear to have ceramic insulators, so I suspect they aren't just directly connecting phase to earth (notwithstanding that it doesn't work very well that way...)

I'm not asking about the switches that are on the pole or the wires connecting the lines to the switches.

What is the purpose?

When I first started seeing them, I just figured they were parts of the grid taken offline and jumpered together as a safety in case someone accidentally energized the other end, but then I noticed they were on distribution wires that were definitely active, supplying homes.

Is there a fairly comprehensive website that has examples of modern grid equipment, as I see other things on the poles that I don't know the function.

[image: Powerline on pole with wires/jumpers between phases and earth]

Comment: Might they be overhead wire current transformers that have not been connected up yet? https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZzBU.png

Comment: Do you mean like a can-style transformer? Could be, but this is a residential area and those are most often connected to only one of the 3 phases to provide power to residences.

Comment: No, CTs monitor line current (one per phase) and are quite small in comparison. If they are CTs then their wire leads are just resting on the earth wire awaiting connection to some monitoring equipment (but, I could be miles off hence no formal answer).

Comment: Was the power company working on the HV lines nearby - they may be temporary grounds installed to ensure the HV lines are safe to work on - but that doesn't explain the insulator-like things at the HV end of those wires.

Comment: These have been there for at least a full year or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of surge arresters is a good one. It looks like a motor-operated group-operated switch is mounted on this pole, in the closed position when the photograph was taken. If a surge comes down the line when the switch is in the open position, the voltage transient doubles due to the open point. If this doubled voltage exceeds the withstand capability of the switches or the strain insulators that tie the conductors to the pole, then those points can arc over, potentially damaging the insulator and/or the switch, and the arc will generally not self-clear, thus requiring line protection to operate. From what I see, it looks like there are arresters on the top cross-arm connected across each of the strain insulators. That will protect each of those insulators and the switches when they are open.

The hanging arresters (called "line arresters", if that's what they are) are connected line-to-neutral with the two outside phases hanging on the left side of the photo and the middle phase connected on the right side of the photo.

Metal-oxide varistors (MOVs) generally fail to a short when they fail, so line arresters are designed with a ground lead disconnector, which is basically a powder charge that will explode if excessive current flows, allowing the ground lead to disconnect and fall. In that case, line protection has to operate to clear the fault, but it can subsequently reclose rather than having to stay out of service until the arrester can be replaced.

Here's a [photo gallery](http://www.arresterworks.com/resources/photo.php) of various kinds of arresters. The "Pole top switch with Arrester Protection" and "Transmission Line Arresters" look like the most similar applications even if the devices themselves look somewhat different.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a lighting arrester.  I'm *kinda* guessing, but those are a sensible location and they look right.  Picture from [this site](https://www.hubbell.com/hubbellpowersystems/en/Products/Power-Utilities/Arresters/Distribution-IEEE/Normal-Duty/PDV-65-Optima-Arrester-10-2-kV-MCOV-7202-Hardware/p/2736583).

[image: Lighting arrester from Ohio Brass]

Comment: I think that sounds like a good guess. So with that terminology, I went searching and I didn't see any google results that showed that style with a cable, and I notice that on top of the cross bar, there are 6 little insulator-looking items, which look more like your picture.

Comment: I think the cable gets added when they install it -- again, a guess.  I build itty bitty clean circuits, not great big dirty ones.  As to the insulator-looking things, those are insulators.  Pretty much all high-voltage insulators have that profile, to increase the creepage path for high voltage.  A lightning arrestor is just an insulator that's designed to break down in a predictable way, so you'd _expect_ it to look sorta like an insulator.

Comment: These are transmission line (lightning) arresters. I see them on the high tension lines in my area.